# Nullpointer exception when instantiating an array

Tags: java

I get a `java.lang.NullPointerException` when I run the code below:

```
import org.apache.axis.types.*; //to use UnsignedShort

UnsignedShort a = new UnsignedShort(1);
UnsignedShort b = new UnsignedShort(1);
int c= 123;

VARDATA[] data = new VARDATA[1];

data[0] = new VARDATA();
data[0].setUsType(a);
data[0].setUsIndex(b);
data[0].setUlValue(c);
```

Comment: Please add the stacktrace or the exact location where the exception is thrown from

Comment: Please show the *full* code and not just those lines where *you* can't find the problem.

Comment: And add also a little bit more code. For example part of the UnsignedShort or VARDAT class that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do you get the `NullPointerException`? Which line? Re `VARDATA`, I don't see it imported, so presume it's part of the same package as the code you're running.

For readability I would prefer to set the first element of `data` explicitly, and *then* assign it to the array reference, i.e. something like this:

```
VARDATA[] data = new VARDATA[1];

VARDATA d = new VARDATA();
d.setUsType(a);
d.setUsIndex(b);
d.setUlValue(c);

data[0] = d;
// And so on ...
```

… but that's up to you. Either way, I think you need to post `VARDATA` as I suspect that is where the issue lies here.

Comment: Hello Ben, A slight modification to your code is working perfectly.

VARDATA data0 = new VARDATA();
data0.setUsType(varType);
data0.setUsIndex(varIndex);
data0.setUlValue(varValue);
  
VARDATA[] data = { data0 };

When I define VADATA[] data = new VARDATA[1]; I got error if I assign data[0] = something, the above modified version did the trick. 

Thanks ...

PS: My comments appear in a straight line, how can I format them? This is my first post.

Comment: @user690153 - we can't do a formatted multiline comment, but you can format parts of the comment as `code` - I usually append info like that to my original question.

Comment: @user690153 Glad to hear you got it sorted. Re comments as Andreas_D says, you can only do inline code in comments, using the ` character around the code.